# Getting response from serve the wrong Json format. How to make it respond in required format?

Tags: php, angular

I am trying to create a search Module in my application but the response from my database is in the following format and i am getting a error

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

sa[{"id":"4","worklocation":"Hyderabad","firstname":"Sanjay","lastname":"Tutuki","gender":"Male","aadharno":"0","panno":"2147483647","employeetype":"asdasd","dateofbirth":"2017-07-12","city":"Mumbai"}]
```

How do i make it respond without the term which i searched with? Or how to I get the values in my component without the Error.

This is my code:

service.ts:

```
search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
  }
            searchEntries(term) {
                const baseUrl="http://localhost/Angular/search.php?search="
    return this.http
        .get(baseUrl + term)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Component :

```
export class EmployeeDirectory { 
    data : Data[];
    searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(private dataservice : DataService){

        this.dataservice.search(this.searchTerm$)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data.data;
        console.log(data);

      });
  }

  search(searchTerm$){
    this.dataservice.search(this.searchTerm$)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data.data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
    }
```

Template :

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
   <form method="GET" name="form" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)"  placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" (click)="search(this.searchTerm$)" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>


   <div *ngIf="data">
      <table *ngFor="let employee of data">
        <tr><td>First Name: </td><td>{{employee.firstname}}</td></tr>
      </table>
```

PHP File :

```
<?php 
header("Allow-Access-Header-Origin: *");
$servername ="localhost";
$username ="root";
$password="sandeepchetikam";
$dbase = "mydb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbase);
if(!$conn){
    echo "Error" .mysqli_error($conn);
}
$name =$_GET['search'];
print_r($name);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM newdb WHERE firstname LIKE '%{$name}%' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

And also the function is responding only for first search key up and it's not working for other search items. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You did remove the `print_r($name)` when you were testing this right?

Comment: yes that was the issue. Thanks everyone . Can someone help me with this too?? How do i make the search button as search rather than on key up ?? how to send searchTerm$ for the button?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can google that.

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r($name);
```

Looks kinda suspicious

Answer (score 1):

remove `print_r($name);` from your code. first you print your data so this is also response data and last echo json data also response data so your correct response data change . this is more important if you write html code or echo or print data in your file then it will send as response.

so your total code will be

```
<?php 
header("Allow-Access-Header-Origin: *");
$servername ="localhost";
$username ="root";
$password="sandeepchetikam";
$dbase = "mydb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbase);
if(!$conn){
    echo "Error" .mysqli_error($conn);
}
$name =$_GET['search'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM newdb WHERE firstname LIKE '%{$name}%' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

hope it will help you